# Access: run-time error '2176' - The setting for this property is too long, but it is not

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm not an experienced vba programmer and working with access is not my cup of tea. I've been asked to fix some errors in an MS Access 2010 VB application.

I have the following line of code which throws run-time error '2176' - The setting for this property is too long.

```
grdDocs.RowSourceType = "SELECT tblLicenceDocuments.lDocumentId, " & _
                                "tblLicenceDocuments.sTitle as Title, " & _
                                """"" as Type, " & _
                                """"" as Method, " & _
                                "tblLicenceDocuments.sAvailabilityDetails as Availability, " & _
                                """"" as Format " & _
                        "FROM tblLicenceDocuments " & _
                        "WHERE tblLicenceDocuments.lLicenceId =  1187 " & _
                        "ORDER BY tblLicenceDocuments.sTitle"
```

The sql in question is only 279 characters in length, so the length is not a problem (I could be wrong). I have run the sql and it is valid. I have searched the web with no good leads.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Is 'Type', 'Method', or 'Format' a reserved word in Access?

Comment: Are you maybe mixing up **.RowSourceType** with **.RowSource** ?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196558(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @Tim Williams. Your have eyes like an eagle; they spotted an oversight on my behalf. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant to set .RowSource, not .RowSourceType; As Tim Williams so dutifully pointed out.